# How to get fillable variable as array in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, model

When we create any Model class we create protected variable fillable

I use this like

```
$model = new Demo;
$model->fillable // but now working
$model->fillable() // but now working.
```

Actually i want to loop over that variable

But i don't want to create any extra variable and don't wanto to change variable

type from protected to public.

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Do you want to modify fillable property of the model?

Answer (score 42):

Models have a `getFillable()` method that will return the value of the `$fillable` property.

```
$model = new Demo();
dd($model->getFillable());
```

Comment: Does the Laravel Model have a property that returns the final values of whatever set in fillable or guarded property?

Comment: @DendiHandian `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\GuardsAttributes` does not have a specific method to do this, but you can do `$model->getFillable()->merge($model->getGuarded());`

Comment: @CameronWilby Good approach, but if everyone else wondering, the above code is incorrect for the use :smile . We can't merge the fillable with guarded, but somewhat like using array_diff()

Comment: @DendiHandian Are you looking for `$model->only($model->getFillable())`?

Comment: and no build in method where you can get that without making a useless empty object :) still - in 2021... now that is just stupid

Answer (score 4):

I use this in laravel 9.*

```php
app(Model::class)->getFillable()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this-> getAttribute('column_name')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access fillable even without instancing the model you could define it outside the class:

```
//outside the class
define('DemoFillable', ["a", "b"]);

Class Demo extends Model{
    
    protected $fillable = DemoFillable; //use previous definition
}
```

Then you can access DemoFillable from anywhere.

Only works on php 7+

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

> The value of the constant. In PHP 5, value must be a scalar value (int, float, string, bool, or null). In PHP 7, array values are also accepted.

If you must work on php5 you could use a $GLOBALS variable instead